# How could i do a similar effect to this Shiny/Holographic pokemon card effect

Tags: materials

[video example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tewbf.jpg)

How would i be able to recreate this effect inside shader nodes, i have the wave textures and everything but i'm not sure how i would do the iridescence effect like that

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.